# ASP.NET Menu PopOutImage CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, menu

when I use the asp:Menu the popoutimage is by default enable, I know I can disable it, but I kind of like it. The thing is I modified my background & foreground of the menu and so the popoutimage arrow is blended in the background. Is there a way to change the settings of this? And how should I go about?

Is there maybe a CSS tag I could use for this?

Thx

EDIT:

the markup language is shown as this:

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="ctl00_TopNavigation_1 TopNavItem ctl00_TopNavigation_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$TopNavigation','Material')" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Material</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img src="/ASP%20Test%20WebApp/WebResource.axd?d=nNpXA-tgytzmQJwzxJnoSKNU-6BcLlO3wOo_dawXyOs1&amp;t=634050991608503994" alt="Material uitvouwen" style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" /></td>
```

So I have no idea :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You the the code-behind, you can do something like:

```
MenuObject.StaticPopOutImageUrl = "/path/to/your/image";
```

or, if you don't care to have an image you can do:

```
MenuObject.StaticPopOutImageUrl = "about:blank";
```

*edit* - even better:

```
MenuObject.staticEnableDefaultPopOutImage= False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the source of the rendered page.
Find the menu in the source.

See if you can see the mark-up that displays the poputimage.
If you cant see the mark-up see if there is a css class on the parent element.

Comment: I edited my topic showing my markup, no idea how to go about this tho